# Code injection in every file on host

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, shared-hosting

I have a hosting with one main application written in Laravel 4, and several sub-domain sites mostly made with Wordpress.

Last few days I have a big problem since every PHP file on my hosting, regardless of it's location gets altered by adding some code at the beginning.

Has anyone had this kind of problem? I guess it comes from Wordpress being hacked, but is there a way to localize it to that specific wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat rare for WordPress itself to be 'hacked'.  More likely is a poorly written or compromised plugin or theme has been used.

Themes can also use scripts which can have very dangerous security flaws in them.  One such example is TimThumb, which was part of many legitimate themes, but contained a security hole which allows an attacker to write to any files owned by the same user on the server.  More here: http://blog.vaultpress.com/2011/08/02/vulnerability-found-in-timthumb/

My advice:

- Update WordPress
- Update all plugins
- Remove any unneccessary plugins and only use ones from larger vendors ([JetPack](http://jetpack.me) can often replace many other plugins but you know it will be safe and secure as it's built by Automattic, the creators of WordPress)
- Change your FTP password
- Change your admin password

Answer (score 1):

I have faced these similar situation before..There are many plguins to protect the website from code injection techniques..

here is a plugins for wp to stay safe from many of the atttacks

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulletproof-security/

You can read more about how to prevent code injection from ur website [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/preventing-code-injection--net-36946).

PS: Sorry if i misunderstood ur question..